# Symfony2 Amazon SDK Setting Credentials Dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services

I've gotten `Amazon SDK` to work well with **Symfony2**. It involves loading the `sdk.class.php` right into the `autoload.php`. I'm not sure if this is best, but it seems be.

But my main problem is loading the Credentials. **Amazon wants you too..** edit the `config.inc.php` and put it either in the `vendor directory` OR in the `HOME`. Option 1 isnt good because it involves modifying a Repo which would get overwritten on updates and `HOME` doesn't work because it's outside my project directory.

**What I'm doing now,** *inside `autoload.php`* is loading the `sdk.class.php` and then running `CFCredentionals:set(array());` .. my code is below. Normally I'd want to do a Dependency Injection or use Parameters.. but I can't figure out any other way to get the Credentials loaded. Also, I don't want to load them when I instantiate the Services. like `$e3 = new AmazonE3(array($a,$s));`. It's so much cleaner and stream lined to have the credentials pre-loaded so you can just use `$e3 = new AmazonE3();`

**So this is what works -- but there's got to be a better way**

```
 require_once __DIR__. '../../vendor/AmazonPHPSDK/sdk.class.php';
    CFCredentials::set(array(
       '@default' => array(
            'key' => '1dfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZ82',
            'secret' => '8tCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfjB+Q',
            'default_cache_config' => 'apc',
             'certificate_authority' => false
        )));
```

There's nothing wrong with how Amazon wants us to load the credentials. It just just doesn't seem to go well with the Symfony2 framework. Having an Array with Access Credentials in the autoload.php just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use something like the [AmazonWebServicesBundle](https://github.com/Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle) which looks like it allows configuration via `parameters.ini` or `config.yml`?

---

The documentation for this is [here-link](https://github.com/Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) . Currently, the steps to set the credentials via `parameters.ini` OR `config.yml` are in step 6 and it looks something like this..

```
// app/config/parameters.ini
[parameters]
    ...

    ; Amazon Web Services Configuration. Found in the AWS Security Credentials.
    aws_key                        = YOUR_KEY
    aws_secret                     = YOUR_SECRET_KEY
    aws_account_id                 = YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID
    aws_canonical_id               = YOUR_CONONICAL_ID
    aws_canonical_name             = YOUR_CONONICAL_NAME
    aws_mfa_serial                 = YOUR_MFA_SERIAL
    aws_cloudfront_keypair_id      = YOUR_CLOUDFRONT_KEYPAIR_ID
    aws_cloudfront_private_key_pem = YOUR_CLOUDFRONT_PRIVATE_KEY_PEM
```

Comment: I've read through that documentation and _Cybernox_ has a **TODO** : `Refactor aws-sdk-for-php` (or find what we can pass in during instantiation to circumvent) so the `config.inc.php` file presence issue isn't an issue. This suggestion does get us a step closer.Here's the link [Cybernox todo](https://github.com/Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/todo.md)